I can't align the pointer in C
Seems pointer can't use B | operator in gcc
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE (4096UL)
#define PAGE_MASK (~(PAGE_SIZE-1))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *p1, *p2=malloc(1024*1024);
    p1 = p2 & PAGE_MASK;
    free(p2);
    return 0;
}

Did the above but got compiler error
test.c:10:17: error: invalid operands to binary & (have ‘void *’ and ‘long unsigned int’)

Only offsets can be applied to pointers. Logical operations exists only for integral types. You must convert to intptr_t (the integral type sized for pointer in #include <stdint.h>), do the operation, and convert back to pointer.

@dalfaB In case of void* you can't even apply offsets, that would be non-standard.

This question is similar to: Why can't you do bitwise operations on pointer in C, and is there a way around this?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You would need to cast the pointer to uintptr_t to be able to do those kinds of operations,
#define PAGE_MASK (~((uintptr_t)PAGE_SIZE-1))
p1 = (void *)(((uintptr_t)p2) & PAGE_MASK);

but note that if p2 isn't already aligned, p1 will now point before the memory allocated by p2.
The proper way would be to use aligned_alloc:

void *aligned_alloc( size_t alignment, size_t size );


So:
int main() {
    void *p1 = aligned_alloc(PAGE_SIZE, 1024*(size_t)1024);
    //...
    free(p1);
}

Note that "The size parameter must be an integral multiple of alignment" so using PAGE_SIZE in the size calculation would probably be a good idea:
int main() {
    void *p1 = aligned_alloc(PAGE_SIZE, 256 * PAGE_SIZE);
    //...
    free(p1);
}


If you can't use aligned_alloc (for example you are on embedded system and use own allocation strategy like memory pools).
void *align_pointer(void *ptr, uintptr_t alignment)
{
    uintptr_t p2 = (uintptr_t)ptr;        
    uintptr_t aligned_p2 = (p2 + alignment - 1) & (~(alignment - 1));
    return (void *)(aligned_p2);
}


& (~(alignment - 1)) is a problem if size_t and int narrower than uintptr_t as the and can lose significant bits.  Better to insure math is at least uintptr_t width.
